# How can I keep my code visible in Eclipse while searching?

Tags: eclipse

I click CTRL-F to find a string in Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) on Ubuntu 18.10, and the  code gets grayed out.

See the code behind the Find dialog in the screenshot.

Since I typically need to step through a few instances of the target string, this is frustrating: I have to close the find dialog to see the text.

[image]

How can I keep the code from being "grayed out" while I Find text?

Comment: The graying is probably done by the operating system for all dialogs. Which operating system do you have? Is Ctrl+J instead of Ctrl+f what you are looking for? Otherwise, there is a plug-in for a search field in the lower editor area.

Comment: OS: Ubuntu (question edited). Ctrl+J looks like it could be useful for some parts of the Ctrl-F function, thanks. But I wonder how this 'grayed out' look can be prevented.

Comment: Do you see this grayed out background also for non-modal dialogs in other applications?

Comment: I have never experienced this problem with other applications. How would I test this?

Comment: I'm not a Ubuntu user and can't help you here. Is the background also grayed out for the non-modal _Help > Install New Software..._ dialog? The plug-in I mentioned is called [Find Bar for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/find-bar-eclipse#group-screenshots).

Comment: "Help > Install New Software" also grays out the background, though of course that is acceptable in this case,

Comment: Note: In case this is an operating system issue Ubuntu as suggested -- I created this ticket https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112264/

Comment: Is this only a visual effect or is the main window blocked preventing you from editing the code in the editor?

Comment: This dialog is nonmodal--I can click on the background and edit text while the dialog is open. But that doesn't help with the dialog's core function of taking me to desired text.